# Process for discovering if a "new" type of question is on-topic for any given SE site

Tags: discussion, scope

On one SE site I'm currently in the process of attempting to find a logical way to help suggest why "**questions of a type**" should or should not be defined as being **on-topic or off-topic**, but I'm unable to find a definite resource for how to discover and document why this is the case in a meaningful way.

Clearly, every "new" type of question is not reviewed, so I'm guessing it is only topics that are flagged by users within a given SE's meta site for review that are analyzed for the topic's fitness for the related SE site; also likely because the user contest that type of question was labeled off-topic as a reason for the question being closed.

**What is an objective way to analyze and document if a topic is a fit for a given SE site?**

If it matters, here's the related meta question: [Should we allow market research questions?](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/803/should-we-allow-market-research-questions)

Comment: Not sure if this counts as "new" type of question considering that "marketing" is explicitly listed in the FAQ's topics-okay-to-cover section. It seems to me questions of that type are definitely on-topic and would be either fair game or too localized. (And I'd argue the latter since I doubt that kind of question would be of help to anyone else almost ever, it's way too specific. But that doesn't make it off-topic.) In general, when I am considering posting a question but not sure if it's okay, the first thing I do is consult the FAQ.

Comment: (Nevertheless I think your question about evaluating a a new type of question is very good -- I'm just not sure if your example is a great case because that type of question is listed in the FAQ's topics section)

Comment: @Ben Lee: Agree, though the poster of the question has stayed that: (1) being "too local" is not the issue, being on-topic is (2) no one was able to find a definite definition of "too local", though I made the case that "too local" real just means it's of use to only the person asking the question and that 2+ upvotes meant three people found the question of use and the question was not "too local"; meaning there is no require that a question be of value to everyone, and being of use to 3+ people in my opinion is a question of value.

Comment: While I agree on your take on stance about topicality, I disagree with your assessment of value/helpfulness. Since it's off topic for this question, I've elaborated on my reasoning in a comment to your answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 4):

Read the site's FAQ, linked at the top of every SE page. The FAQ outlines what is on-topic and off-topic for every site.

Fine-tuning of site scope takes place on the Meta site for each SE site, also linked at the top of every SE page.  You can browse the questions there about site scope, or ask your own.

The StackExchange Blog is a great place to see general discussions about scope.  In particular:  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/