# Arbitrary closing of a question, do I have the right to know why my question was closed?

Tags: support

I've posted a question about "[Process for discovering if a “new” type of question is on-topic for any given SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126001/process-for-discovering-if-a-new-type-of-question-is-on-topic-for-any-given-se)" and requested feedback on why another question of mine was closed for deletion here "[Why was my question closed?](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/809/why-was-my-question-closed/)" -- and at this point based on the lack of meaningful reply left wondering what recourse I have for what to me seems like an arbitrary closing, and deletion at some future point.

I've had lots of questions closed/deleted/reopened, but I've never run across a question that was closed and I was unable to understand or get an explanation of why the question was closed, and have no idea what to make of it.

Any suggestions?

I might add that it's not just my question, but questions of a type that appear to be arbitrarily being closed/deleted, but there's a [question by the mod on that topic here](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/803/should-we-allow-market-research-questions), I've voiced my opinion, and have elected to focus just on my question at this point, since I feel I have a right to know what the basis was for closing my question when it appears to be [on-topic per the site's FAQs](http://answers.onstartups.com/faq).

Comment: Market Research questions generally fall into the broad category of "Not Constructive." See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Thanks you for the both the answer and comment, I'm reflecting on them and will reply later today. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

From the OnStartups FAQ:

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?** 
>  Answers.onstartups.com is a site for entrepreneurs starting and running new businesses.
>
> Topics include financing, hiring employees, renting an office, legal,
> marketing, sales, compensation plans, banking, payroll, benefits, and
> more. This is the place to come with specific questions or to seek
> specific advice from your peers.
>
> If you look at the tags page, you'll see some of the topics that are
> discussed here.
>
> Please avoid:
>
> - ***Wide open questions.*** Don't write a sentence and expect to get a page back. A question like "How can I sell more of my product"
>   deserves an encyclopedia article. Try to scale back to something more
>   specific.
> - "Rate my business" or "Please review my startup" or "what do you think about my web page" or "what do you think about my company name".
>   If you have a specific question, that's fine, but if you want feedback
>   on your business, ask your friends and colleagues, and, even better,
>   ask some people who might be your customers.

It seems pretty clear to me that [your question](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/37076/how-to-estimate-the-value-of-a-person-going-from-being-obese-to-non-obese) fits into the category of "Wide Open Questions."

Also, from the FAQ:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
> entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your comment [under the other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126403/152184), but I posted a reply and ping you here just in case you don't see my reply.

Comment: On rereading my original comment, it seemed a bit brusque. Zuly is very smart; she knows that giving a customized, detailed explanation to every new user about why their question was closed doesn't scale. :)

Comment: Please explain how my request to know if "$2000 in expenses per year per obese person" is a wide open question.

Comment: Already did....

Comment: "seems pretty clear to me" is not an explanation.

Comment: In thinking about it, your answer is "no you don't have a right to know why your answer was closed" -- the additionally information is not related to my question, and while I would like to know the reasoning, I didn't notice you'd change the subject -- and it's unclear to me why you've posted this here, and not on my related question.

Comment: You're just being petulant.  Do your own research; there's plenty of material in the metas and in the faq that already adequately explains the closure.

Comment: If you believe I'm being bad-tempered, then I don't believe you know what the meaning of the term. I know you're attempting to help, and I'll leave it at that - though I will say that to my knowledge I've never replied to anyone saying they didn't have the right to understand something, nor given that they wanted to understand, didn't take the time to help make sure they understood.

Comment: Are you saying that the real reason the question should have been closed was because it was "Not Constructive", not the two reasons given so far, those being the first, "Too local", then the current, "off-topic"; meaning **market research would not be fit for any SE site**, not just this site?  If so, then I can understand that being a reason, though it has been a very confusing path to that information, and I might add that you're the first as far as I know to give that as a reason.

Answer (score 5):

Meta questions about questions on a *specific* Stack Exchange site should really be asked on *that site's* Meta, rather than here on the general meta site for the entire Stack Exchange network.

That allows you to get targeted feedback from the community in which you asked the question, and ideally, from the individual users/moderators who actually voted to close your question.

Thus posting the meta question [that you did](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/809/why-was-my-question-closed/) is exactly the way I would advise you to proceed.

In my experience, both here for questions on Stack Overflow and on the other SE 2.0 sites that I participate on, questions inquiring about the closure of a particular question receive relatively rapid responses, and often, as I said, by the very same people who voted to close the question!

If you're not having that luck on Answers.OnStartups, that seems to be something that you should take up with the community there. Communities are free—and in many cases, even encouraged—to establish their own standards for questions and set their own parameters for topics.

We could give you *general* advice on how to ask questions that won't get closed and *general* feedback on the types of questions that are discouraged across the network, but I suspect you already know most of this, as you can read it in the various FAQs.

That said, I don't think your assessment of the Answers.OnStartups community is at all fair. Zuly, the moderator who closed your question, seems very willing to attempt to explain her rationale for closing the question. [Her meta question](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/803/should-we-allow-market-research-questions) that you linked to was actually opened of her own volition in an attempt to solicit community feedback with respect to this type/category of question. As she said in a comment to [your original question on that site](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/37076/how-to-estimate-the-value-of-a-person-going-from-being-obese-to-non-obese):

> ...I'm closing it for now as "too localized", but I started a thread on meta to discuss this further. These type of questions have come up in the past, so I think it's important to discuss this, and come to a decision on whether we allow them or not. If the consensus is that they should be allowed, we can easily reopen your question. Feel free to share your thoughts.

I must say, I'm not really sure what else you wanted or expected. You've been given not only the right to know why your question was closed (as your title asks here), but also the ability to voice your opinion about the nature of the site itself. That seems pretty fair to me. You aren't guaranteed that others will *agree* with your opinions.

Comment: Agree, with your answer in general, but also confused by it, I did ask on the specific Stack Exchange site and the mod that closed the question, changed the reason from "too local" to "off-topic", but then failed to state why the question was off-topic.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I did, and was told "[Please re-read all the comments. It is all there](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/803/should-we-allow-market-research-questions#comment990_803)" -- which is why I posted the question, and my comment to the mod's answer, [which wasn't an answer, but just states the reason for the question being closed was changed](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/809/why-was-my-question-closed/#comment993_810).